# Send a HTTP post request with a false source ip address

Tags: http, tcp, ip, jmeter

Is it possible to send a http POST/GET request by changing the source IP address to a false one. I am not bothered about not being able to get the response back(because of the false IP).

Thanks

Comment: No you can't with JMeter, Jmeter is for load testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use an inexistent IP address to do IP-spoofing.
Regarding you not being interested in response, That's not how socket work.

Comment: Yeah it totally makes sense, but the problem I am trying to solve is that I want to loadtest a load-balancer and all my load generating VMs are behind a single NAT and the load-balancer logic uses the source-ip to do some processing. So any suggestions on how to go about this would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Check out the "Source IP Address" parameter of HTTP Request sampler. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

As the explanation of the parameter suggests, you need to alias IPs which you want to use.

Comment: what you explain works when IP exists, in the question user says it doesn't exist

Comment: exactly.. moreover I assume this works only when multiple IPs are configured to the machine running jMeter (either by multiple network cards or virtual network adapters)